# Solspace Freeform return path {csrf_token}

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, parse, csrf

I am having an issue, probably parse related. Using Solspace Freeform I am trying to include the {csrf_token} in the return path but its not working.. my code is as follows for the form:

```
{exp:freeform:form
                   form_name="whitepapers"
                   required="email|full_name|company|job_title|whitepaper|my_unique_hash|partner"
                   return="/{segment_1}/{csrf_token}"
                   inline_errors="yes"
                }
```

It returns to domain.com/segment/%7Bcsrf_token%7D with an error: Error: The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

I am trying to use the CSRF token to check against buy storing it in a hidden field and using it to display the entry on the return. From this example: http://support.solspace.com/support/solutions/articles/4000032469-how-to-make-freeform-forms-editable-without-using-the-entry-id-in-the-url

Could anyone shed some light or offer a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried adding parse="inward" to the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to parse order, where the `{csrf_token}` variable wouldn't be parsed yet until the `{exp:freeform:form}` tag has fully rendered, which would be after the parameters have been parsed.

Comment: The example I was following was from the Solspace support so assumed it would work. I just need to show the users details on the return page, not possible?

Comment: The example solution assumes you're generating your own hash (however you might do it), not using the CSRF token.